# Usage de « gare » comme une préposition

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu, noms

Lorsqu'un complément de lieu est une gare, on peut des fois l'exprimer de plusieurs manières :

> Je vais à la gare d'Austerlitz.   (description)
>   Je vais à Gare d'Austerlitz.   (nom propre (de la station de métro), pas d'article)
>   Je vais à Paris-Austerlitz.   (nom propre (de la gare SNCF), pas d'article)
>   Je vais à Austerlitz.   (nom propre (abréviation du nom de la gare), pas d'article)
>   Je vais gare d'Austerlitz.   (‽)

Cette dernière construction est bizarre : on omet la préposition ! Le mot *gare* se comporte ici comme une préposition.

On peut utiliser cette construction aussi bien pour un lieu où l'on va que pour un lieu où l'on est, et pas forcément dans le cadre d'un voyage en train :

> Je suis gare d'Austerlitz, j'ai un rendez-vous devant le kiosque à journaux.
>   Je vais prendre le train gare d'Austerlitz.
>   Je passe gare d'Austerlitz acheter un billet.

Je ne sais pas à quel point cette construction est répandue. Pour moi, elle est parfaitement idiomatique. La SNCF ne rechigne pas à utiliser cette construction ([« Chopin prend le train gare d'Austerlitz »](https://www.gares-sncf.com/fr/gare/frxyt/toulouse-matabiau/actualite/10464/chopin-prend-train-gare-dausterlitz)). On l'utilise aussi à Bruxelles ([« alerte à la bombe dans un train Gare du Midi »](http://www.lalibre.be/regions/bruxelles/alerte-a-la-bombe-dans-un-train-gare-du-midi-5384c1753570af48fcf5504a)).

Je ne trouve pas d'emplois sur le web ailleurs qu'à Paris et Bruxelles, probablement parce que les autres villes soit n'ont qu'une gare, soit ont des gares qui ont des noms propres —
 on peut dire « à Perrache », « à Flandres », etc., mais « à Lyon » ou « à Midi » ne passent pas. À Paris, la construction marche pourtant aussi bien avec les gares dont le nom n'est pas ambigu (Austerlitz, Montparnasse, Saint-Lazare) que celles où le mot *gare* est nécessaire (Gare du Nord, Gare de l'Est, Gare de Lyon). Pour ma part j'utiliserais aussi l'expression dans des villes de banlieue qui ont plusieurs gares (« je vais gare Rive Gauche » à Versailles) mais pas lorsque le nom de la gare est juste le nom de la ville. Il arrive que les touristes francophones transportent l'expression à des villes étrangères (« [nous arrivons par le train gare de sants a barcelonne](https://les-bons-plans-de-barcelone.com/arriver-en-tgv-a-barcelone/#comment-20327) » (*sic*)).

Il ne me vient pas à l'esprit d'autre construction similaire. Ça ne marche pas pour un port ou pour un aéroport, par exemple.

D'où vient cette étrange construction ? Est-ce qu'elle fait partie d'un phénomène plus général ? Est-elle connue, utilisée ailleurs qu'à Paris et Bruxelles ?

Comment: `Je vais gare d'Austerlitz.`, Ça ne veut pas dire "Je vais en direction Gare d'Austerlitz", que cela soit ma destination ou non ? Sous-entendu en métro car la ligne va dans les deux sens, et par commodité, la station est assimilé également à la gare de train au besoin en fonction du contexte ?

Comment: @Larme Non, ça veut dire que la gare est ma destination. Si je compte descendre du métro avant, je dirais « je prends le métro en direction d'Austerlitz », ou tiens, intéressant, « je prends le métro **direction Austerlitz** » (ou « direction Place d'Italie » ou « direction Bobigny » — ça marche avec n'importe quelle station ou commune). La gare peut désigner tout le complexe ferroviaire, y compris les galeries commerçantes, et même éventuellement les alentours immédiats de la gare (les arrêts de bus par exemple).

Comment: @Gilles `Il ne me vient pas à l'esprit d'autre construction similaire` - avec *place* ? *Rue* ? Tout ce qui désigne une adresse exacte, en fait...

Comment: Ca fonctionne aussi avec "place" : "Je vais place de la République", "La manifestation termine place de la Nation". Je pense que c'est une ellision du "à" de la deuxième forme que vous proposez.

Comment: @guillaume31, Distic: ah oui ! C'est une réponse partielle : ça décrit une catégorie de noms. J'aimerais quand même savoir comment on en arrive à supprimer la préposition. Un complément circonstanciel sans préposition n'est pas un phénomène courant en français.

Comment: Grevisse consacre une page à l'ellipse de la préposition mais rien trouvé d'autre que « La préposition est parfois ellipsée ; dans ce cas, le rapport existant entre les deux termes est suffisamment suggéré par la simple juxtaposition des mots. » Mais tous les exemples ne sont qu'avec  des compléments du nom.

Comment: @jcm69 Non, on dirait « je vais **rue** Poissonnière ». Et ça n'a rien de parisien, on peut très bien aller route de Paris à Trifouilly-les-Oies. Par contre, je vais **à** Villejuif-Léo Lagrange (mais pas chercher du pain, je ne prends pas le métro pour ça). Aucun rapport avec la RATP.

Comment: @HydrangéacéeslesHydrangelles Je ne comprends pas la question. Ce n'est pas du style télégraphique. Il n'y a pas de raison de l'écrire avec un deux-points ou autre ponctuation avant le mot « gare », on ne fait pas de pause à l'oral et ça casserait la syntaxe de phrases comme « je vais gare Montparnasse acheter un billet ».

Comment: C'est bien vrai en effet, je suis d'accord, mais c'est surtout que je voulais comprendre pourquoi l'absence de la préposition fait en sorte que vous sentez gare comme préposition ; mon exemple préserve la fonction du mot gare. Je vais y réfléchir davantage. Merci !

Comment: Peut-être un parallélisme à faire avec la remarque trouvée dans Grevisse au chapitre « emploi de certaines prépositions » (Remarques particulières) à *rue* : « Dans l'indication du domicile ou de l'adresse, on supprime généralement *dans*, *sur*, *Il habite Boulevard Voltaire*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il me semble que Laure/Grevisse ont raison. Par ailleurs, j'entends assez régulièrement:

> Je vais boulevard St Antoine,
>
> Je suis place de la Comédie,
>
> Le magasin se trouve rue Faubert,
>
> Vous aurez vos séminaires salle Jean Jaurès

D’après [« Le syntagme prépositionnel — l’omission de la préposition » par Gabriel Wyler](http://www.gabrielwyler.com/page276.html) :

> ¶ Préposition marquant un point dans l'espace
>
> § Les adresses
>
> On indique les odonymes sans préposition :
>
> il habite rue de l'Université
>
> il travaille avenue de l'Opéra
>
> je l'ai croisée place de la Victoire
>
> il y aura une réunion porte de Versailles
>
> [...]
>
> ¶ Les odonymes
>
> La préposition *de* est le plus souvent omise devant les noms dans les
> odonymes. Cependant, *de* est requis quand
>
> § le nom est précédé d'un titre (avenue du Maréchal Foch)
>
> § le nom n'est pas un nom de personne (boulevard du Montparnasse)
>
> § le de est un de nobiliaire (quai de Conti, rue de Condé)
>
> [...]
>
> ¶ Survivances du génitif
>
> Hôtel Dieu
>
> Fête Dieu

Bien qu'il y ait une règle, il semblerait que nous ayons pris des libertés car je n'ai jamais entendu: 'boulevard du Montparnasse'.

Définition du mot odonyme dont je ne connaissais pas le sens, d'après le [Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/odonyme) :

> Choronyme désignant une voie de communication routière, ferroviaire ou autre

Comment: Il y a les mêmes comportement pour les circonstants de temps du type *ce matin*, *hier*, *vendredi*, *le dimanche*, etc.