# Omission de la préposition après le verbe « aller »

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, verbes, syntaxe, indications-de-lieu

Dans quelques éditions des « Misérables » de Victor Hugo, le personnage Enjolras dit:

> Tu serais un homme [autrement, tu serais homme] à aller barrière du Maine.

Et un peu plus tard:

> Tu iras barrière du Maine.

Voici deux exemples: [1](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/17518/17518-h/17518-h.htm#Chapitre_VI), [2](https://books.google.com/books?id=w08XAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=j%27en%20ai%20une%20vague%20ambition&source=bl&ots=uSZfamBLLG&sig=ACfU3U3aU2t_7hmK1udN6YidCD0wDrXs9w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPy_nk0LrkAhVGCKwKHU5SCDIQ6AEwAXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false). Il y a d'autres éditions, comme ces deux-là ([1](https://books.google.com/books?id=mShCBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT857&ots=aoj3mYM8Tr&dq=j'en%20ai%20une%20vague%20ambition&pg=PT857#v=onepage&q&f=false) et [2](https://books.google.com/books?id=kg5bAAAAQAAJ&lpg=PA320&ots=H-tCXAo242&dq=%22%C3%A0%20la%20barri%C3%A8re%20du%20maine%22&pg=PA320#v=onepage&q&f=false)), dans lesquelles on lit « aller à la barrière du Maine », mais pourquoi celles-ci omettent-elles la préposition entre « aller » et le complément du verbe? Cette omission n’est-elle pas interdite?

Comment: Et aussi la réponse à cette question https://french.stackexchange.com/q/26865/358 et

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Au contraire, on peut construire le complément adverbial sans préposition avec *rue, boulevard* etc.<sup>1, 2</sup> et c'est plutôt le tour avec la préposition qui pourra être qualifié de « tour primitif » (LBU 314 c 2°) :

> Arrivé rue Neuve-Sainte-Geneviève. (Balzac)
>  Il alla dîner rue
>   Saint-Jacques. (Flaubert)
>  Courez rue du Ranelagh prévenir Madame
>   Constance. (Giraudoux)
>  Je me trouvais justement avenue Hoche.
>   (Modiano)
>  [...] de se montrer ou non cours de l'Intendance
>   avec un apprenti en casquette. (Poirot-Delpech)
>  Dans un immeuble qui
>   se construisait quai d'Orsay. (L. Weiss)
>  Vous viendrez villa Andréa
>   ensemble. (Fl. Delay)
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14e, § 314 c 2° (exemples tirés de) ]

On peut faire un certain rapprochement entre le complément d'objet et le complément adverbial et dans ce contexte, on trouve chez certains verbes une concurrence entre ces compléments : généralement (hormis *rue, boulevard* etc.) on peut employer le verbe [*habiter*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/habiter) directement ou avec une préposition de lieu (*J'habite Paris* ou *À Paris*). (LBU14 § 297 b 6°)

Il y a des différences dans l'emploi des prépositions *(à), dans* et *sur* pour marquer le lieu selon qu'on réfère à l'idée d'un volume (*dans*) ou à celle de l'accès ou de la vue (*sur*), entre autres. Quand le mot *rue* etc. s'accompagne de la dénomination, il peut être précédé de *dans/sur* selon ces différences ou employé sans préposition ni article (*Je l'ai croisé avenue d'Iéna*). (LBU14 § 1049 b 1°)

> « La préposition *à* se justifie quand le lieu est envisagé comme un
>   point : *Il arriva À la rue de Grenelle*. On la trouve parfois dans
>   d'autres cas, ce qui est généralement blâmé : *Ils habitaient un bel
>   appartement, À la rue des Minimes* (PAGNOL, *Gloire de mon père*, p.
>   69). — Elle est plus courante avec *quai* : *Ça lui rappelait leurs
>   petites séances d'autrefois, AU quai Napoléon* (FLAUB., *Éduc.*, II,
>   6). — *Elle transporta sa mélancolie* [= elle déménagea] *AU quai
>   d'Orléans* (GREEN, *Jeunesse*, p. 232). — Elle est normale quand on
>   désigne par métonymie une institution ayant son siège dans cette rue :
>   [ *Ribbentrop et son ambassadeur en France [...] sont reçus au Quai
>   d'Orsay* [= ministère des Affaires étrangères à Paris] (SEGHERS, *La
>   Résistance et ses poètes*, p. 23). LBU14 § 99 b].
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14e, § 1049 b 1° ]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> La question est distincte de celle de la tendance à supprimer du complément du nom des mots *rue* etc. la préposition même dans des cas où traditionnellement on a *de*, soit quand le nom de la *rue* etc. est celui d'une personne précédé d'un titre (*place DU Roi Albert*) ou quand le complément n'est pas un nom de personne (*Avenue DE Versailles*). (LBU14 354 a)</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> On notera par ailleurs que cet emploi n'apparaîtrait pas nécessaraiement dans toutes les variétés régionales. Voir [*«Rue X»: La grammémisation à l'œuvre dans la parole* (1997)](https://www.persee.fr/doc/flang_1244-5460_1997_num_5_9_1152), Jeanne-Marie Barbéris, à la note 5.</sub>

Comment: Peut-être que ce document de la note 2 ajoute à la réflexion.

Answer (score 4):

Il n'y a pas d'erreur, il est tout à fait correct de dire :

> aller barrière du Maine.

La barrière du Maine désigne ici un lieu, un quartier délimité et  non pas une barrière physique. D'ailleurs je ne sais pas si à l'époque des *Misérables* la barrière existait encore physiquement.

De la même façon qu'on dit :

- Je vais rue du Maine.
- Je vais boulevard Montparnasse.

on dit :

- Je vais barrière du Maine.

La question qu'on pourrait donc se poser c'est de savoir pourquoi certaines éditions ont mis « à » suivi de l'article défini ? À mon avis (tout à fait personnel, j'en conviens) c'est que les correcteurs des éditions comportant le **à** connaissaient mal la géographie et/ou l'histoire de Paris et ont pensé à une barrière au sens physique et ont fait une correction mal à propos.
Je viens de vérifier l’exemplaire des *Misérables* dans la Bibliothèque de la Pleïade, réputée pour la qualité de son travail d'édition, et qui est très vraisemblablement basée sur les manuscrits originaux de Victor Hugo, il y est bien écrit « Tu serais homme à aller barrière du Maine ! ».  Victor Hugo connaissait très bien Paris et savait qu'il parlait du quartier. Tout comme à la ligne suivante  il écrit :

> Je suis capable de descendre rue des Grès...

Par contre avec d'autres verbes la préposition s'imposerait, par exemple, comme il écrit à la suite :

> Je suis capable de descendre rue des Grès, de traverser la place Saint-Michel

il aurait écrit « de traverser la barrière du Maine ».

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais tout d'abord que les romanciers peuvent faire parler leurs personnages comme bon leur semble.  On ne peut pas imputer à Victor Hugo une faute de français d'Enjolras, ni de Jean Valjean ou du père Fauchelevent, ni de qui que ce soit d'autre.  Le roman serait bien fade si les misérables des Misérables s'exprimaient tous comme des académiciens.

Ensuite, le tour *aller barrière du Maine* n'est pas fautif.  On dit bien :

> - J'habite avenue Jean Jaurès.
> - T'arrives Gare de l'Est, tu vas Gare du Nord et tu prends le train pour Lille.

C'est plutôt dans un contexte de déplacement d'un point à l'autre, d'une adresse à l'autre d'une ville qu'on l'emploie.

Enfin, *être homme à faire quelque chose*, c'est être capable de faire cette chose.  On ne peut pas le remplacer par *être un homme* ici.

La barrière du Maine à l'époque de l'action du roman :

[https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_barrières_de_Paris#/media/Fichier:Paris-Barrière_du_Maine_1820-03.jpg](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_barri%C3%A8res_de_Paris#/media/Fichier:Paris-Barri%C3%A8re_du_Maine_1820-03.jpg)

Comment: Je mettrais bien +10 si je pouvais rien que pour ton premier paragraphe.

Comment: Un auteur qui dit sait dire autant de choses dans 2 toutes petites phrases : « C’était la sombre étoile de la police qui se levait dans l’égout. Derrière cette étoile remuaient confusément huit ou dix formes noires, droites, indistinctes, terribles. » est pour moi un génie de la langue française.

Comment: @Laure   Nous sommes d'accord.  He's the boss!  J'avais recommandé je ne sais plus où dans un commentaire la petite conférence de David Bellos sur les Misérables qu'il a donnée à Shakespeare and Co à Paris (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oypGwRdOXdI).  Je l'ai trouvée passionnante.

Answer (score 1):

Il est correct de ne pas mettre de préposition lorsqu'on indique un endroit par le nom donné à la voie de communication (*odonyme*).

> J'habite Rue de la République
>
> Je vais Place de la Nation
>
> Je me rends Chemin des Postes

On peut aussi rencontrer le même usage pour des noms de lieux qui ne sont pas à proprement parler des odonymes mais qui y sont assimilés en pratique:

> je vais Gare du Nord

On peut imaginer que par métonymie, les locaux appellent la voie qui passe devant cette barrière (qui est en fait un bâtiment d'octroi), voire le quartier entier, également "barrière du Maine", et l'utilisent dès lors également comme un odonyme.

Il y en a en tout cas un exemple similaire à Bruxelles, où le bâtiment d'octroi de l'ancienne "barrière de Saint-Gilles" a disparu, mais le carrefour où il se trouvait est néanmoins toujours appelé "barrière de Saint-Gilles" de nos jours.

Answer (score -1):

Il n'y aurait pas de faute  dans cet usage si l'on considère que la barrière dans une ville, en particulier [Paris](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_barri%C3%A8res_de_Paris), ce n'est pas le nom d'un quartier mais plutôt un nom de location piétonnière, praticable par un véhicule ; il est similaire à l'usage de « aller place », dont on peut trouver beaucoup de cas  dans la littérature ; de nos jours c'est un usage très courant (en particulier en donnant des indications) ; on le retrouve pour tous les noms d'artère et d'endroits piétonniers (place, square, boulevard, rue, impasse, …). Si on considère donc « barrière » comme un nom du même type que « place », pour rester consistant on ne peut pas reconnaitre de faute.

*quelques exemples pour le mot « rue »*

- Il aborda un commissionnaire, lui mit dans la main cinq francs, et le chargea d'aller rue Paradis, chez Jacques Arnoux, pour s'enquérir près du portier «si madame était chez elle» (FLAUB., Éduc. sent., t. 2, 1869, p. 99).
- Si tu veux donner à Nathan quelque bonne leçon, nous irons tous trois chez toi; là je te prouverai, pièce en main, que tu peux l'empêcher d'aller rue de Clichy, sous peu de temps, si tu veux être bonne fille (BALZAC, Fille Ève, 1839, p.197).
- Ici, nous ne sommes pas très bien placés pour le boucher. Je crois qu'elle est obligée d'aller rue Lepic. Il y en a bien un plus près, au coin de la rue Lamarck (...). Mais elle s'est brouillée avec lui (ROMAINS, Hommes bonne vol., 1932, p.100).
- Elle s'efforçait de ne pas montrer sa jalousie (...) chaque fois qu'il quittait la charcuterie pour aller rue Pirouette, et qu'elle s'imaginait les plaisirs défendus qu'il devait y goûter (ZOLA, Ventre Paris, 1873, p.743).
- Au moment où Eugénie Garin, ou, si vous le préférez, la Turquoise quittait, vêtue en ouvrière, son petit hôtel pour aller rue de Charonne, un coupé de remise qui montait la rue de Clichy vint s'arrêter devant la grille du jardin (PONSON DU TERR., Rocambole, t.2, 1859, p.383).
- Je voudrais, évitant un éclat, gagner la fin de mai en continuant à aller rue de Berri, me faire rare, rare, rarissime, cet été à Saint-Gratien (GONCOURT, Journal, 1891, p. 52).

On trouve de même beaucoup de cas pour « [aller place](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aller+place&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caller%20place%3B%2Cc0) ».

Comment: *Un nom de location piétonnière, praticable par un véhicule* C'est surréaliste.

Comment: @jilliagre Not at all. Many pedestrian zones or malls are accessible to service vehicles.

Comment: @HarryAudus Many are indeed, but you missed the point. The issue is that LPH pretends to be a native French speaker but often does mistakes very typical of English speakers. He actually wrote: *The name of a pedestrian rental accommodation, usable by one vehicle*, a sentence that can arguably be considered surreal. In that answer, he also wrote *pour rester consistant* assuming the meaning was the same as "to stay consistent" but *consistant* (that means: nourishing, substantial, solid) can't be used in French here. The right expression should have been *pour rester cohérent*.

Comment: @jlliagre Aha! Thanks. Now I understand.

Answer (score -3):

Je suis d'accord avec vous, l'omission de la préposition est dans ce cas interdite.

Il faut savoir que Victor Hugo est plutôt connu pour avoir pas mal de fautes dans ses textes. Je ne serais pas surpris que ce soit simplement l'une d'elles.

Il est aussi possible (invraisemblable) que cette omission ait été légale en son temps.

Je joins une référence de TV5 monde sur les fautes des grands écrivains Français: https://information.tv5monde.com/culture/les-fautes-de-francais-des-grands-ecrivains-67960

Comment: Avant de ma lecture de cet extrait, j'avais rencontré des fautes grammaticales parmi des autres écrivains, mais celles-là ne me semblaient pas si fondamentales et si évidentes.

Comment: Une affirmation telle que « Il faut savoir que Victor Hugo est plutôt connu pour avoir pas mal de fautes » se doit d'être justifiée car elle est en contradiction avec  ce que beaucoup de critiques littéraires et linguistes ont dit sur la langue de Hugo.  Le lien que tu donnes mentionne quelques fautes d'accord (dont au moins une serait discutable comme faute ou pas faute d'ailleurs) , et ne valide en rien l'assertion comme quoi il était «  plutôt connu pour avoir pas mal de fautes ».