# Why is there no preposition (i.e. "à") before "voie" in the sentence "Le train va arriver voie deux" ?

Tags: prépositions, verbes

The intended meaning is *The train is going to arrive **on** track two*.

In general, *arriver* is followed by *à*. For instance *Il est arrivé **à** Paris* or *Elle est arrivée **à** la gare*.

So why there is no preposition before *voie* in the sentence *Le train va arriver voie deux* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just an idiomatic construction that has very possibly come into being as a result of the heavy use of "arriver *sur la* voie x" in train stations. You can still say "arriver sur la voie deux"  ([ref. 1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22arriv%C3%A9%20sur%20la%20voie%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr), [ref. 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22arriver%20sur%20la%20voie%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)) . "Arriver à la voie" is not said when you are talking about trains ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22arriv%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20la%20voie%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)).

Comment: Thank you. If *sur* is the correct preposition, then it is similar to English. According to the links you provided *Arriver à la voie* looks possible for other vehicles or humans. Can we also say "arriver sur la voie" for other vehicles or humans in some context?

Comment: @Xfce4 In general , no; if the meaning of "arriver" is different then there is a possibility. ex. quand nous sommes arrivés sur la voie qui nous avait été indiquée il commença à pleuvoir.  — you'll have to find the difference in the meaning of "arriver" in this example.

Comment: What is the meaning of "arriver" in your comment? It is possible for a non-native speaker to interpret the sentence in several ways.

Comment: @Xfce4 Whereas in your question the verb means "to have reached a destination, that is a place where you are going to stay for some time", in the example it means "to have reached a place", but nothing more; however the place must be of a special sort  (voie, boulevard, avenue, passage,…). Nevertheless, there is a matter of usage involved in this context and, for instance in the case of rue, you  use "à" rather than "sur".  (1/2)

Comment: @Xfce4 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arriv%C3%A9+sur+la+rue%2Carriv%C3%A9+%C3%A0+la+rue&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carriv%C3%A9%20sur%20la%20rue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carriv%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20la%20rue%3B%2Cc0 (2/2)

Comment: @Xfce4 There is no possibility of ambiguity.

Comment: I thought the sentence you wrote could be an idiom or a metaphor which would explain why *sur* was used instead of *à*. Anyway, do you say that for *rue, voie, boulevard, avenue, passage,...* I can use *arriver sur* if I am going to stay there for a while ?

Comment: @Xfce4 No, the sentence I wrote aims at showing another meaning of  "arriver" that is compatible with the use of "sur"; therefore, it is a matter of idiomatic choice but the construction "arriver sur" is not an idiom. // No, on the contrary, you can use "sur" when the thoroughfare is not a destination but just a place you happen to reach.

Comment: I can continue asking but don't want to bother you. Thanks a lot. Maybe someone else will also contribute.

Answer (score 5):

***Voie 2*** is a *complément circonstanciel de lieu*. It answers to the question:

> ***Où** va arriver le train ?*
> *Le train va arriver **voie 2**.*

*Voie 2* can be removed or moved without breaking the sentence:

> Le train va arriver.
> Voie 2, le train va arriver.

That sentence uses no preposition because *voie 2* is similar to an address, here a track, just like would be a street or a building with which we would also typically avoid any preposition:

> *J'arrive rue Lafayette.*
> *On se retrouve bâtiment D.*

If you insist to use a preposition, ***à*** is is rare but usable:

> *Descendu du train à Brainel'Alleud, j'entends un message rassurant, annonçant que le direct pour Charleroi arrive **à la** voie 2.*, Pierre Guilbert, Denis Mayeur, Didier Colart , *Le B.A.-Ba de la communication*, 2013

but ***en*** or ***sur la*** would be less uncommon, despite being definitely much rarer than just ***voie 2***:

> *Le train va arriver **sur la** voie 2.*
> *Le train va arriver **en** voie 2.*

but

> *La train va arriver (**au**) quai numéro 2.* (platform #2)

With my two examples, ***à*** would be the best preposition (if any):

> *J'arrive **à la** rue Lafayette.*
> *On se retrouve **au** bâtiment D.* (or ***dans le*** if you make clear it will be inside the building)

See also: [Omission de la préposition après le verbe « aller »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/38371)

Comment: Thank you. As far as I know "voie" is a generic word and not confined to train tracks only. So is it possible that we can use "à" with "voie" in any context? Also, it is kind of weird that we can use "à" with "rue" while we can't with "voie" -as "rue" itself is a kind of "voie".

Comment: Yes, *voie* means "lane", "way" (as in railway). Actually, it is not really forbidden to use *à* with *voie*, it is just very rare but *il arrive à la voie deux* is possible.